# WSO2 Enterprise Integrator get current sequence name

Tags: wso2, sequence, integrator

I would like to retrieve the name of a process's currently running sequence.

There's a proxy-defined property to retrieve similar information for a proxy service ($ctx:proxy.name) described in [Wso2 ESB GET PROXY NAME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12300816/wso2-esb-get-proxy-name?r=SearchResults&s=1|120.0484)

Does something similar exist for sequences? I've tried the obvious ($ctx:sequence.name) and that results in a null value.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, it is not possible to obtain the sequence name in the mediation

Comment: Thanks much for the confirmation. I'll continue with a convention of setting a property at the beginning of sequences for the purposes of database logging.